# Super Algebraic Numbers?

Tags: algebraic-numbers

Let $P$ be a non-zero polynomial with real algebraic coefficients; prove or disprove the following

"All real roots of $P$ are algebraic numbers"

Comment: What do you mean with "with real algebraic factors"?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: You probably mean, "with real algebraic _coefficients_"? If so this is a near-duplicate of [On the meaning of being algebraically closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71267/on-the-meaning-of-being-algebraically-closed)

Comment: Real Sorry! just editted: factors----->coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the polynomial is $p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ has all $a_i$ algebraic over the rationals. Let $K:\mathbb{Q}$ be an algebraic extension in which $K$ is a splitting field of all the minimal polynomials of the $a_i$. Then $$Q(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in Aut(K:\mathbb{Q})}(\sigma(a_n)x^n+...+\sigma(a_1)x+\sigma(a_0))$$

is a polynomial with rational coefficients, since it is invariant under $Aut(K:\mathbb{Q})$. All roots of $p(x)$ are roots of $Q(x)$, since $p(x)$ is one of its factors.